# LINQ query from ViewModel to Controller ViewBag to display in SelectList in View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of learning MVC, and it is proving to be quite an admirable foe seeing as how I'm used to web forms.

There are so many things I can do in web forms that I can't seem to replicate in MVC, and if I can I'm so lost when it comes to actually implementing it. But my question is as follow;

I have a table

```
public partial class Patient
{
    public Patient()
    {
        this.PatientHousings = new HashSet<PatientHousing>();
    }

    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public bool Incarcerated {get;set;}
    public bool Released {get;set;}
    public bool Deceased {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<PatientHousing> PatientHousings {get;set;}
}
```

And this is a other table

```
public partial class PatientHousing
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public Guid PatientID {get;set;}
    public bool CurrentPrevious {get;set;}
    public string Building {get;set;}

    public virtual Patient Patient {get;set;}
}
```

Okay, so in web forms I would just bind a dropdownlist to a datasource with the proper query. Well I can't do that with MVC, and I have to use the controller which I'm still bashing my head against the wall with.

I've read that I need to create a ViewModel to help me with this, so I've created the following

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    public List<Patient> patients {get;set;}

    public PatientViewModel(){
        DATAEntities db = new DATAEntities();
        patients = db.Patients.Include(r => r.PatientHousings.Where(h => h.CurrentPrevious == true)).Where(x => x.Incarcerated == false && x.Released == false && x.Deceased == false && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LastName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting this error

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

Someone please help. I'm so lost right now it isn't even funny.

**To clarify:** What I need to do is, create a select list in a view that lists all patients that are not incarcerated, released, or deceased.

Comment: When you say table, are you trying to generate an HTML table? Or do you mean is the table you're referring to a database table which is the source for these classes? I'm confused at where the drop down list comes into play and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What you should do is map in your viewmodel class the fields you only need and later pass the list of viewModels to your view. About the error, you can't filter related entities in an Include call, you need to project your query using a viewModel as I described earlier.

Comment: Lambda expression for Include accepts only dotted notation for references and Select for collections but you can't do any filtering.  In order to filter, you need separate queries

Comment: @Zeph Yes, when I say table I mean the model that references the table in the DB. What I'm trying to achieve is this; my "Patient" table has multiple patients that have different statuses. I need to know how to filter out those patients so that I can put them inside of a dropdownlist in a view. I forgot to add the code for the view in the question.

Comment: *What I need to do is, create a select list in a view that lists all patients that are not incarcerated, released, or deceased.* so you mean: `List<Patient> patients = db.Patients.Where(x => !x.Incarcerated && !x.Released && !x.Deceased).ToList();`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot use a 'where' inside Include as it isn't one of allowed navigation properties.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

[Is there a way to defined .Where inside .Include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068518/is-there-a-way-to-defined-where-inside-include)

You can try using Select or an expression without it and then filter out further using Where.